# When i try to declare variables in h file it shows the error LINKER COMMAND FAILED WITH EXIT CODE -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

How can i globally declare a variable in objective c? when i try to declare variables in h file it shows the error

> LINKER COMMAND FAILED WITH EXIT CODE -1

Comment: You should include the specific error, and not just the exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a global variable like this:

```
extern int GlobalInt;
```

The extern part tells the compiler that this is just a declaration that an object of type int identified by GlobalInt exists. It may be defined later or it may not (it is not the compiler's responsibility to ensure it exists, that is the linker's job). It is similar to a function prototype in this regard.

In one of your source files, you define the GlobalInt integer:

```
int GlobalInt = 4;
```

Now, each file that includes the header will have access to GlobalInt, because the header says it exists, so the compiler is happy, and the linker will see it in one of your source files, so it too will be happy. Just don't define it twice!

Answer (score 1):

In header files, declare variables as `extern`.

```
extern NSInteger myGlobalInteger;
```

In a single implementation file (`.c` or `.m`), declare as normal.

```
NSInteger myGlobalInteger;
```

If you leave off the `extern` in the header, you cause a new variable with the same name and scope to be created in every file that imports/includes the header.  This causes the linker trouble because you end up with duplicate symbols.

Declaring the variable as `extern` in the header tells the compiler that somewhere exists such a variable with the given type.  It doesn't worry about where it is really defined.  At link time, the linker will see all these references to the real declaration and fix-up the references.

Answer (score 0):

Please define corresponded variable in .m file as well. Please find the below eg:

For a standard global variable, not persistent when the app is terminated and restarted, add this to a header file (`*.h`) of your choice:

```
extern NSInteger MYGlobalVariable;
```

Then put this in the implementation file (`*.m`, `*.c`, `*.cpp`):

```
MYGlobalVariable = 0; // Or ny other default value.
```

That is how you do a bread and butter global variable.